# Determining the algebraic structure of $\Bbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I've a question that asks me to determine the algebraic structure of $\Bbb Z_{26}$.

Now I'm always puzzled when the operation is not defined.

Clearly, $\Bbb Z_{26} = \{0, 1, \dots, 25\}$. So, it is just a set not an algebraic structure, right?

However:

$(\Bbb Z_{26}, +)$. This is an additive group.

$(\Bbb Z_{26}, .).$ This is not a multiplicative group because not every element has a multiplicative inverse, e.g $gcd(2, 26) = 2.$ So, $2$ does not have an inverse.

$(\Bbb Z_{26}, +, .)$. This is a ring.

So, it seems to me that it could be just a group or a ring. Is anything wrong with my reasoning ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question means by "algebraic structure", but usually when asked to determine the structure of some algebraic object it means to find how it decomposes into simpler objects.

As an additive group, $\mathbb Z_{26}$ is a cyclic group and so indecomposable.

As a ring, $\mathbb Z_{26} \cong \mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{13}$ is a decomposition into indecomposable rings.

Answer (score 0):

Every $\Bbb Z_n$ is also a bilateral modulus over $\Bbb Z$ in a unique way.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)